# Comments an additional Code when implementing interface

Tags: vb.net, interface, comments

If I implement the IDisposable-interface I get some comments and a field also.
How can I achieve this with my own interface?

```vb
Private disposedValue As Boolean

Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            ' TODO: Verwalteten Zustand (verwaltete Objekte) bereinigen
        End If

        ' TODO: Nicht verwaltete Ressourcen (nicht verwaltete Objekte) freigeben und Finalizer überschreiben
        ' TODO: Große Felder auf NULL setzen
        disposedValue = True
    End If
End Sub

' ' TODO: Finalizer nur überschreiben, wenn "Dispose(disposing As Boolean)" Code für die Freigabe nicht verwalteter Ressourcen enthält
' Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
'     ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie Bereinigungscode in der Methode "Dispose(disposing As Boolean)" ein.
'     Dispose(disposing:=False)
'     MyBase.Finalize()
' End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Ändern Sie diesen Code nicht. Fügen Sie Bereinigungscode in der Methode "Dispose(disposing As Boolean)" ein.
    Dispose(disposing:=True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can not. The VB code editor has additional knowledge of the dispose pattern that is not visible in the interface declaration itself.

Comment: Hallo nach Burgdorf. All I want is a Public Shared Readonly ...line when implementing the interface. Otherwise I have to write it every time and I will forget it for sure.

Comment: [Interfaces in VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/) cannot have Shared members. Only instance members and no fields and no constants. You can only have methods, properties and events.

Comment: Are you really asking about interfaces or are you actually meaning inheritance?

Comment: @Hursey, I think he is asking about having the VB code editor automatically adding a default implementation with additional comments and members that are not part of the interface, like `Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)` not being an interface member.

Comment: precisely what olivier wrote